# Is there a way to insert a list of information into another table? in C# codefirst SQLite

Tags: c#, android, sql, sqlite, xamarin

**I want to record my friends list on the table.**
In the tutorial I saw, we could take a picture of each friend. To do this, we created a string property called ImageName. But now I want to take more than one photo for each friend, but these codes get errors.

```
    public class Friend
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int FriendId { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public List<int> ImageId { get; set; }
    }

    public class FriendImage
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Error**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhs5x.png)
if you know true way please help me. **Thank you**.
**sorry for *bad English.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store more than one photo you'll need a Many-to-many relationship in order to avoid repeated records. You have to mark it as many-to-many

```
[ManyToMany(typeof(FriendImage))]
public List<int> ImageId { get; set; }
```

and insert a list with:

```
SQLiteConnection.InsertAll(list_of_FriendImage);
```